# Determining whether a user is associated with an object through another class in a django template

Tags: django, templates

I have a **user** model, an **item** model, and a **possession** model to store data about a user possessing an item. When a user is logged in and viewing an item, I want to display an 'add to my items' button, unless the user already has the item.

I was trying this code in the template:

```
{% if not user.possession_set.filter(item=item.id) %}    
<input type='submit' value='add to my items' />
{% endif %}
```

where
**item** is the foreign key name for the item object in my possession model and
**item.id** is the primary key for the item being displayed to the user

but I get this error:

```
Could not parse the remainder: '(item=item.id)'
```

I'm thinking I can't use the .filter() function since that is for querying the database? I found django's template filters, like this one:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/templates/builtins/#get-digit
but there aren't any that can be combined to filter for a certain value of item. It seems I would have all the information in the template to do this, since I'm getting the user and it's possession_set, which should have the item field for each possession, so I'm thinking it's just a syntax thing?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Good question, I was also wondering what the canonical way to do this is in django, but it seems a bit convoluted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a custom template filter for this.

```
def owns(user, id):
    return not user.possession_set.filter(item=id)
```

Then, in your template:

```
{% load mystuff %}
{% if user|owns:item.id %}
```

Check the Django docs at http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/howto/custom-template-tags/ for more info. Not sure if passing `item.id` as the filter argument will work, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use such complicated expressions in the template, only in the view. Compute the information, whether user can have this button in the view and pass a single True or False value to the template. For example:

in view

```
allow_addition = not user.possession_set.filter(item=item.id)
```

and in template:

```
{% if allow_addition %}
  <input type='submit' value='add to my items' />
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Yup! That should work.  I was wondering what would be a good implementation if there were many items that you wanted to do this with?  Makes it a bit harder.